# Finding a Parametrization for a Linear Path in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, parametrization

I try finding a way to parametrize **in Complex Plane** the path: $$ \left \{ z \in \mathbb{C} | \begin{cases}
 z = a+ib, (a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 , \\ 
 |a| + |b| = 1 
\end{cases} \right \} $$

Trivially, the result would be a piecewise defined path ie. a union of 4 lines.

While trying, I found that the parametrization in $ \mathbb{R} $ for the real valued function which would induce the same graph as this path doesn't hold in $ \mathbb{C} $.

In fact, the values $ a,b $ tend to be non-constant functions of one of another. And this situation shows that we need to choose another *parameter*.

For the new parameter, I would suggest using $ |z| $, thus over the couple $ ( \rho, \theta ) $ where $ z = \rho {e}^{2 \theta \pi i} $ in polar form.

But my calculations haven't led to any solution.

Thanks for your help

Comment: It's a piecewise linear function of $\theta$. If that's not good enough, you should explain what properties you want the parameterization to have.

Comment: can we explicit the function? or is it just a complex path?

Comment: Are you asking if we can write down a formula? Of course; it's just linear interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of parameterising this path, it really depends on what properties
you want.

Let $x(t) = \max(1-x,x-3)$ for $x\in [0,4]$ and $4$-periodic otherwise. Let $y(t) = x(t-1)$. Then $\gamma(t) = x(t)+iy(t)$ for $t \in [0,4]$ will suffice.

You could also try $\gamma(t) = {1 \over \|e^{it}\|_1} e^{it}$ for $t \in [0,2 \pi]$.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I got my answer especially with the last function. But I repeat that your second example with $ y(t) = x (t-1) $ is exactly the classical adaptation of the $ \mathbb{R} $-way of thinking which doesn't hold.